# Count number of a value of a field in big table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I need to count the number of lines which have a specific value in one of its fields.

Lets say :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = 'MyValue'
```

Problem is that there more than 1.000.000 rows and the execution time is too long (more than 60s)

What can I do in this specefic field to make this Request run faster?

Comment: You should add an index to the table on the "MyField" column.

Comment: Do you run this query often? Do you always look up the same value or different values? How many distinct values are there in the column? Depending on the answer to these questions an indexed view or filtered index could also be considered.

Comment: there are basecally 5 distinc values and NULL.
I used a nonclustred index like this :
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX INDEX_NAME ON MyTable (MyField ASC)

Comment: @GMastros For the cardinality stated above this would be a bit of a waste.

Comment: @MartinSmith Except that creating the index took execution time from "(more than 60s)" to "less than 1 second".  Just guessing here, but I suspect that the execution plan is now using an index scan, but the index only has this 1 column so scanning a narrow index instead of scanning a (possibly fat) table.

Comment: @GMastros - Yes it will be an improvement on no index at all but a non covering index on such a low selectivity column is basically only ever going to be useful for a `COUNT` query so may as well just use an indexed view.

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't disagree with you.  Please note that my original comment existed prior to knowing that there are only 6 distinct values in the column.  This is also why I didn't post the comment as an answer... I didn't know for certain that it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you search only exact value of column ('MyValue'), you should create an index on the MyField column.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_MyField ON MyTable (MyField ASC)
```

If you want to search word in phrase from column - create Full Text Search index (as in answer of Mari).

Comment: Great! The CREATE NONCLUSTERED statement took some time to execute but my query runs now in less than one second! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You say the NCI speeds things up to less than a second and that the table has 1,000,000 rows with 6 distinct values so that still means on average 167,000 index rows need to be counted to answer the query.

Additionally a non covering index on such a non selective column is unlikely to be useful to satisfy additional queries.

An indexed view with pre-calculated counts would allow the `SELECT` to be more or less instant and have less space requirement and maintenance overhead (no need to store 167,000 rows with MyValue1 followed by another 167,000 for MyValue2 and so on)

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) AS Count,
       MyField
FROM  dbo.MyTable    
GROUP BY MyField

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON dbo.MyView(MyField)
```

And then

```
SELECT Count
FROM   MyView WITH ( NOEXPAND)
WHERE  MyField = 'MyValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Full Text Search**

For text based columns, full text search is always required to be performed under several times. In such situations full text index is used.

Syntax:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name (column_name1 […], column_name2 […]) …
```

This will increase your performance

Comment: I don't have FULLTEXT installed in my machine!

Answer (score -3):

You can try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'MYFIELD%'
```

Comment: I think this is not quite correct answer. Why you believe that `LIKE` will help?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'MYFIELD'` And `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='MYFIELD'` are same. `LIKE` is used when we want to use wild card characters. Also `=` suppress the white spaces after string while executing. So it wont help performance.

Comment: Fully agree with @Nithesh.

Comment: Fully agreed with Devart & Nithesh